# Power automate is sending the same email 7 times to my inbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, power-automate, sharepoint-email

I am using the simple **Power Automate** template **"when an item is created in SharePoint Online, send an email (v2)**. My email has **7** loops. The workflow works, but **I am getting 7 of the same emails in my inbox** when I test it.

What do I need to do to set Power Automate to send only 1 email to the person submitting the information?

Here is my email:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Move send an email action outside of loops. If you need any information from within loop to email, use variables/arrays to store the information temporarily and outside loop, use these variables inside send an email action.

Comment: @ganeshSanap, can you recommend a set of procedures I can review? I’m not a programmer. So, I am not familiar with what you’re describing. I will post my email example tomorrow when I am at work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, please let me know what you think.